# How to use NSSharingService in Catalyst?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I try to use NSSharingService to add my catalyst app to share actions  sheet on macOS but get error `NSSharingService is unavailable in Mac Catalyst`.

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
extension NSSharingService { //Error: 'NSSharingService' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst
    class func shareContent ( content: [AnyObject], button: NSButton ) {
        let sharingServicePicker = NSSharingServicePicker (items: content )

        sharingServicePicker.showRelativeToRect(button.bounds, ofView: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MaxY)
    }
}
#endif
```

I find the article about how to use AppKit in Catalyst [here](https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit)

My steps:

1. Create macOS `ReaderTranslatorAppKit` bundle and set principalClass="ReaderTranslatorAppKit.ReaderTranslatorAppKit" in Info.plist

```swift
open class ReaderTranslatorAppKit: NSObject, ReaderTranslatorCommonInterfaces {
    public func test() -> String {
        "test 1"
    }
}
```

2. Added `ReaderTranslatorAppKit` bundle in Embed as macOS platform
   [image: Added it to plugin]
3. Create `ReaderTranslatorCommonInterfaces` common protocol

```swift
public protocol ReaderTranslatorCommonInterfaces {
    func test() -> String
}
```

4. Load ReaderTranslatorAppKit in `SceneDelegate.swift`

```swift
...
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.builtInPlugInsURL?.appendingPathComponent("ReaderTranslatorAppKit.bundle"),
        let bundle = Bundle(url: bundlePath) {

        bundle.load()

        if let cls = bundle.principalClass as? NSObject.Type,
            let plugin = cls.init() as? ReaderTranslatorCommonInterfaces { //Error: plugin is nil
            print(plugin.test())
        }
        print(bundle)
    }
}
```

**Result** 
I get nil when casting `cls.init() as? ReaderTranslatorCommonInterfaces`. What's wrong?

## Update

I solved my issue by creating macOS project instead of Catalyst, sharing code between two projects and using `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter` and `UserDefaults(suitename:)` to send objects from my extension to the app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226827/4067700)